# Viewing a Server's GAC from another machine using Windows Explorer doesn't see all the DLL's

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dll, gac

When I view a Windows Server's GAC (through Internet Explorer) I can see all the dll's that have been registered for the cache. However, when i navigate to the same location from another server, some of the dll's are not visible. Why is that? I have the same rights on the each server (administrator). Machines are both WK28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GAC folders are a virtual file system.  They are not real folders with real files in them.  What you see in the virtual filesystem is based on what assemblies are available to the version of the dotnet framework available to the system running explorer.exe.